# How to hide image after animation using css?

Tags: html, css, fadeout

I tried the following code To Fade Out The Image ,

```css
.splash-wrapper {
  animation: fadeIn 4s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 4s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 4s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 4s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 4s;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3.1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.splash-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #86FF0000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3.1s;
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  from{margin-left: 0vw;}
  to{margin-left: -150vw;}
}
```

```html
<div class="splash-wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
```

It fades out the image but it's reappearing again and even never fades or becomes invicible. How can i hide the image completely after the animation? .
Should i also mention it's visibility?

Comment: where is your html code? put your code in snippet. How to ask question Read it here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the ``animation-duration`` and ``animation-delay`` for ``.splash-wrapper`` is double and ``@keyframes slideOut`` isn't used...

Comment: You mean that i should remove any one of the animation-duration and animation-delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```css
.splash-wrapper {
  animation: fadeIn 4s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 4s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 4s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 4s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 4s;
  
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #86FF0000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3.1s;
  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  from{margin-left: 0vw;}
  to{margin-left: -150vw;}
}
```

```html
<div class="splash-wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Check [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property

```
.splash-wrapper {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with `animation-fill-mode: forwards` or you add it directly to your animation call:

```css
animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
```

**Working example:**

(I removed the unused `@keyframes slideOut`, the double CSS-code and the `animation-duration`, because you defined the duration already directly in the animation call)

```css
.splash-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #86FF0000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
  animation-delay: 3.1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="splash-wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
```

---

If you want to disappear the `.splash-wrapper` instead of just getting invisible, you can animate the `height` too:

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; height: 100vh; }
  75% { opacity: 0; height: 100vh; }
  100% { opacity: 0; height: 0vh; }
}
```

(75% ist just an example - you could also take 99% o.s.)

**Working example:**

```css
.splash-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #86FF0000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 4s forwards;
  animation-delay: 3.1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; height: 100vh; }
  75% { opacity: 0; height: 100vh; }
  100% { opacity: 0; height: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; height: 100vh; }
  75% { opacity: 0; height: 100vh; }
  100% { opacity: 0; height: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; height: 100vh; }
  75% { opacity: 0; height: 100vh; }
  100% { opacity: 0; height: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; height: 100vh; }
  75% { opacity: 0; height: 100vh; }
  100% { opacity: 0; height: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 1; height: 100vh; }
  75% { opacity: 0; height: 100vh; }
  100% { opacity: 0; height: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="splash-wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
```

---

If manipulating the height is still not enough and you really want to hide the element after the animation, you have to use Javascript. You could use the `animate()` function, the `setTimeout()` function for the delay and a promise ( `then()` ) for setting the `display` property:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  splash_wrapper.animate(key_frames, timing_options).finished.then(function() {
    splash_wrapper.style.display = 'none';
  });
}, 3100);
```

**Working example:**

```js
const splash_wrapper = document.querySelector(".splash-wrapper");

const key_frames = [
  { opacity: '1'},
  { opacity: '0'}
];

const timing_options = {
  duration: 4000,
  iterations: 1,
}

setTimeout(function() {
  splash_wrapper.animate(key_frames, timing_options).finished.then(function() {
    splash_wrapper.style.display = 'none';
  });
}, 3100);
```

```css
.splash-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #86FF0000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash-wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it works But After Hiding It, All The Elements Of My Website Has Become Non-Clickable. I suppose the image didn't go away . It has just become invisible.  So how to make it go away after dissappearing?

Comment: You could animate the height too - see my updated answer...

Comment: If thats not enough, you have to use Javascript - see my updated answer...